# Ruby, Files, Tab Characters

Tags: ruby, csv, tabs

I am parsing a csv file and the file has "\t" characters after every column. Why is it that when I print out the individual lines in terminal or open the file in my text editor that the tab spacing between each of the columns is different?

Comment: Use printf - http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-printf

Comment: HOW are you parsing the file? Show some code and sample data so we know what you're talking about. Don't make us imagine or guess. Or, be a LOT more descriptive; Two sentences aren't adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use tab, you're essentially moving to the next tab location, not moving over a specific distance. To see the difference, try using 4 spaces instead of tab. Or, alternatively, run the following code, and I think it may become clear to you.

```
puts "Hel\tlo world!"
puts "H\tello world!"
puts "Hell\to world!"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, how would I see/know where the next tab location is?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
1   1
12345678    1
```

as a result of

```
puts "1\t1"
puts "12345678\t1"
```

A tab jumps to the next position in 8-space steps (8 spaces is a common distance, but it depends on settings of your editor. For ruby often is 2-space distance is used).

If the previous text is longer then 8 characters, then you jump to the next position and you have the impression of different tab spacing.